# Python openCV find Contours on complex images

Tags: python, opencv

I have problem with finding contours on image from sky (rooftop), this is the original image of the rooftop: [image]

So I need to find all edges, windows on the roof so I could somehow measure area. The result I get it now is: [image]

So problem is with trees, grass road... Could you please give me any tip what should I do? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have converted image to the gray-scale then apply Canny edge detection. Therefore Canny outputs every feature in the image.

I have a two-step solution:

---

- 1. [GaussianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)
- 2. [Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)

---

- To reduce the details in the image (grass, forest, etc.) we need to smooth the image, therefore one solution is GaussianBlur. As you can see from the below table (images were downsampled by 2 to fit the screen) as `ksize` increases lesser features are displayed. I think you can calculate or measure the distance from the output of the `(9x9)` result.

---

|  | `ksize` = (5 x 5) | `ksize` = (9 x 9) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gaussian | [image] | [image] |
| Canny | [image] | [image] |
| Contour | [image] | [image] |

---

Code for `(9 x 9)`

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("7m5oq.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blr = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (9, 9), 0)
cny = cv2.Canny(blr, 50, 200)
cnt, _ = cv2.findContours(cny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img = cv2.drawContours(img, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
cv2.imshow("Gaussian", blr)
cv2.imshow("Canny", cny)
cv2.imshow("Contour", cnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```